# Problem with Table of Contents chapter line breaking

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, hyphenation

I am working with the `book` document class. Concerning the table of contents, is there any way to break the chapter title as you like?  For example, instead of e.g.

> 1. How to effectively feed swiss  brown cows so as to pro-
>      duce more milk

to have

> 1. How to effectively feed swiss brown cows so as to
>      produce more milk

I don't want to make any changes in the body of the rest of the book, only in the table of contents. Is there any way??

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.se!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  Could you please post a minimal working example (MWE) that demonstrates the problem you'd like to resolve?  It'll make it a lot easier for others to help you.

Comment: Have you considered using the optional argument to `\chapter`?  `\chapter[TOC version]{Real version}`?

Comment: no, i am not familiar with TOC.

Comment: i mean with the suggested syntax

Comment: (Just so you know, you can edit comments for a brief period as well.)  Check out [the wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_commands) (just below the table) or, if you'd like, I can turn it into a full-blown answer.

Comment: You could write `\chapter[TOC version]{Real version}`. In the TOC you will have the first argument and in the chapter's title you will have the real version.

Comment: You didn't provide a [MWE (link)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so just a blind shot: Try putting `\begingroup\raggedright\tableofcontents\endgroup` in place of just `\tableofcontents` ?

Comment: @vericulus, @ Dror, @ Jubobs : I tried the titletoc package and it worked fine. Thanks !